# Swagger-Docs/UI file upload unable to receive param value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using following 2 gems for API documentation :

```
gem 'swagger-docs'
gem 'swagger-ui_rails'
```

I have a parameter where I need to upload a file.
I am able to get File Upload in view but unable to get its value in params.

My controller:

```
param :body, 'truck[truck_images_attributes][0][image]', :file, :optional, "Truck Image"
consumes ["multipart/form-data"]
```

Corresponding JSON  by Swagger-Docs :

```
 {
              "paramType": "body",
              "name": "truck[truck_images_attributes][0][image]",
              "type": "file",
              "description": "Truck Image",
              "required": false
            },
 "consumes": [
            "multipart/form-data"
          ]
```

My view :
[image]

Combinations I tried but didn't work:

- `param :form, 'truck[truck_images_attributes][0][image]', :file, :optional, "Truck Image", :body => true`
- `param :form, 'truck[truck_images_attributes][0][image]', :file, :optional, "Truck Image", :format => 'binary'`
- `param :formData, 'truck[truck_images_attributes][0][image]', :file, :optional, "Truck Image"`

Please help me out!

Comment: did you able to upload file using swagger?

Comment: Nope. Started using SwaggerHub with demo data and for testing, using Postman

Comment: Thanks for updating will try other service